# Passing Dictionaries to a Function

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters, arguments

Is there any way to assign keywords to a dictionary's keys and values at the moment they are passed to the function? For instance, `def foo(dic={a:b,c:d}):` where `a` now stores the dictionary's first key, `b` stores the first value and so on.

**NOTE**  A sort of roundabout way I found to do this was by creating `def foo(dic):`, defining `key = list(dic.items())` and then accessing it as a list (for instance `key[0][0]` would be the first key).  I feel like there should be a better way to do this however.

Comment: You can unpack a dictionary to existing arguments, if that's what you mean? `def foo(a, c): print(a, c)` then `foo(**{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'})` would work, for example. If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: More like being able to pass let's say `{0:3,5:3}` to `def foo(dic = {a:b,c:d})` and having `a = 0`, `b=3`, etc...

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: I know how stupid the necessity for this sounds, but I've been assigned a project with very specific function requirements...

Comment: in your example, `foo(dic)`, you can just use `dic` as a `dict`, no?

Comment: What are those *"very specific function requirements"*? What you've outlined in your comment doesn't make any sense to me at all. Also a dictionary doesn't have a *"first key"* really, they're unordered.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a form of pattern matching in function arguments.

Comment: What's confusing is that you're saying `a=0`, which sounds like a call-time restriction, but you're also saying `def ... ` which sounds like your question is about the function definition. If you can sort that out, we'll tell you how to do it.

Comment: Another problem you might run into is the inherent lack of order of `dict`s. In other words, there is no "first key".

Comment: my professor (if he can be called that in good faith) has decided that the best way to pass two euclidean points to the function is in the form of a dictionary.  This means that he would type `foo({0:1,2:3})` and `foo()` would work with the points 0,1 and 2,3.  Since I don't know what keys or values are going to be passed, I need a way to grab them out of the `dict`

Comment: and the way I showed in my question is a bit wordy.  So, I was wondering if there is a way to assign keywords to the keys and values of a `dict` being passed to a function as they are passed, so the function can work with them and do equations with them

Comment: Try this: `dict = {0:1,2:3}; (a, b), (c, d) = dict.items()`, it has to go in the body of the function, it can't go in the signature.

Comment: Based on your comment regarding what your professor said, you are looking for the solution which is the first comment in this post mentioned by @jonrsharpe

Comment: What if both points have the same x value?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's just one of the problems with this. The other is the idiocy of passing a single dictionary instead of something easier to work with in this situation, such as tuple pairs or 2 element lists... or literally anything else...